# How does the Spring4D [inject] attribute function internally?

Tags: delphi, inject, spring4d

I'm trying to create a minimal example, that does the same thing as the Spring4D `[inject]` Attribute. It's supposed to automatically resolve my `TOrderAdapter.FDetailsAdapter`, which I want to manually instantiate inside a *Factory* unit (not like the Spring4D container works, registering interfaces from the outside first). The *Factory* should hand out any desired interfaces requested with `[inject]`.

It is pretty obvious that the code I have can not work (`TOrderAdapter.FDetailsAdapter` not being injected, giving me a `nil` pointer Access Violation on `ButtonClick`, the first use). Reading through the Spring4D source, I fail to see where this **logical piece** is, **that I'm missing** for the desired functionality to work in my example.

```
program OrderDetails;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Order.Adapter in 'Order.Adapter.pas',
  Details in 'Details.pas',
  Details.Adapter in 'Details.Adapter.pas',
  Factory.Adapter in 'Factory.Adapter.pas',
  Factory in 'Factory.pas',
  Order in 'Order.pas',
  Order.View in 'Order.View.pas' {OrderForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TOrderForm, OrderForm);
  Factory.Adapter.Factory := TFactoryAdapter.Create;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

```
unit Factory;

uses
  Rtti, TypInfo;

type
  InjectAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  private
    fServiceType: PTypeInfo;
    fValue: TValue;
  public
    constructor Create(ServiceType: PTypeInfo); overload;
    property ServiceType: PTypeInfo read fServiceType;
    property Value: TValue read fValue;
  end;

implementation

constructor InjectAttribute.Create(ServiceType: PTypeInfo);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fServiceType := ServiceType;
end;

end.
```

```
unit Factory.Adapter;

uses
  Details, Details.Adapter, Order, Order.Adapter;

type
  TFactoryAdapter = class
  private
    FDetailsAdapter: IDetailsAdapter;
    FOrderAdapter: IOrderAdapter;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function Inject: IInterface; overload; // unused
  end;

var
  Factory: TFactoryAdapter;

implementation

constructor TFactoryAdapter.Create;
begin
  FDetailsAdapter := TDetailsAdapter.Create;
  FOrderAdapter := TOrderAdapter.Create;
end;

function TFactoryAdapter.Inject: IInterface; // unused
begin
  Result := FDetailsAdapter;
end;

end.
```

```
unit Details.Adapter;

uses
  Details, Winapi.Windows, SysUtils;

type
  TDetailsAdapter = class(TInterfacedObject, IDetailsAdapter)
  private
    FID: Integer;
  public
    procedure SetID(AID: Integer);
    function GetID: Integer;
  published
    property ID: Integer read GetID write SetID;
  end;

implementation

procedure TDetailsAdapter.SetID(AID: Integer);
begin
  FID := AID;
  OutputDebugString(PWideChar('OrderDetail ID set to ' + IntToStr(FID)));
end;

function TDetailsAdapter.GetID: Integer;
begin
  Result := FID;
end;

end.
```

```
unit Order.Adapter;

uses
  Order, Order.View, Details, Factory,
  Vcl.Forms;

type
  TOrderAdapter = class(TInterfacedObject, IOrderAdapter)
  private
    [inject]
    FDetailsAdapter: IDetailsAdapter;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  OrderForm: TOrderForm;

implementation

constructor TOrderAdapter.Create;
begin
  OrderForm.Button1.OnClick := ButtonClick;
end;

procedure TOrderAdapter.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDetailsAdapter.ID := 5;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container uses RTTI to collect the members that have this attribute and injects the correct services into them.

Comment: So my FDetailsAdapter: IDetailsAdapter; should at least be published? Where in the Spring4D source exctly does this injection magic happen?

Comment: I think I found something: TPropertyInjection.DoInject. Looks like there is a ton of code missing for my example to work... I thought I could jump through the [inject] attribute somehow, but it looks like it's all manual work.